# Getting different sets of plots for the teleportation algorithm in Composer and Lab

Tags: quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit, teleportation

I tried recreating the quantum teleportation circuit (in the Qiskit Foundation Youtube Playlist) both in Lab and Composer and getting different plots for each.

Here is circuit and histogram from Composer
[image]

And here is the one in Lab

[image]

[image]

How do I make sense of these? Link for tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMwovHK2NrE&list=PLOFEBzvs-Vvp2xg9-POLJhQwtVktlYGbY&index=5

Edit : Sorry for the wrong composer circuit earlier, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: they are different, q[0] has an H gate

Comment: When using measurements on the composer, contrary to the qiskit code, it will simulate the circuit with ONE SHOT ONLY, therefore the results you have here, plus aq Luciano said they're not exactly the same circuit

Comment: Is it the behavior already explained in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/simple-hadamard-circuit-gives-incorrect-results/15367#15367)?